# How can I Call API and Set Maker and Polygon on Google map without freezes?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, grand-central-dispatch

In my Map Application I am showing almost **1500 area** in city using  `GMUClusterManager`.
I am calling API and set **GSMarker** and calling function in

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {

 })
```

in API process start with `UIActivityIndicatorView` Show so user can't touch on screen.
After the certain level of zoom I am showing **Plot** of this area it around **300** to **400**.
when plot set using for loop it freeze UI for 3-4 seconds.code is below.

```
for i in self.plotPolygon {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             i.map = self.mapView
         }
}

for i in self.plotMarkers {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         i.map = self.mapView
     }
}
```

**Plot** is getting through API Calling with `DispatchQueue` and set with `GMSMarker` and `GMSPolygon`. photo is given below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsMfF.png)

after certain **zoom out** on plot is remove from **Google map**.
here problem is that every time zoom in process plot API call and in zoom out remove from map and every time `UIActivityIndicatorView` show.

so my question is given below.

**How can I call API and set data without freezes UI and set on Google Map ?**